# Stateflow is not getting updated from room database

Tags: android, android-room, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

I am working on a TicTacToe application. I am trying to access the values stored in my CurrScore table. For which I am returning a flow through Dao. I am converting that flow into stateflow in TicTacToeViewModel. But the stateflow is not getting updated whenever there is any change in entry in CurrScore table.

TicTacToeViewModel.kt:-

```
package com.example.tictactoe.ui

import android.util.Log
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.example.tictactoe.data.CurrScore
import com.example.tictactoe.data.CurrScoreDao
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SharingStarted
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.stateIn
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.update
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

data class GameState(
    val name1:String="",
    val name2:String="",
    val turn:Int=0,
    val matchesWon1:Int=0,
    val matchesWon2:Int=0,
    val draw:Int=0,
    val visited:List<MutableList<Int>> = listOf(mutableListOf(-1,-1,-1),
                                                mutableListOf(-1,-1,-1),
                                                mutableListOf(-1,-1,-1)),
    val winnerFound:Int=-1,
    val prevRecord:Boolean=false
)

class TicTacToeViewModel(private val currScoreDao: CurrScoreDao):ViewModel() {
    private val _gameState: MutableStateFlow<GameState> = MutableStateFlow(GameState())
    val gameState: StateFlow<GameState> = _gameState
    private val currScore: StateFlow<CurrScore> = currScoreDao.currScore().stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
        initialValue = CurrScore()
    )
    init {
        prevRecordExists()
    }

    fun assignValue(i: Int, j: Int) {
        if (gameState.value.winnerFound == -1) {
            if (gameState.value.visited[i][j] == -1) {
                val currTurn = gameState.value.turn
                val visited: List<MutableList<Int>> = gameState.value.visited
                visited[i][j] = currTurn
                _gameState.update {
                    it.copy(
                        turn = 1 - currTurn,
                        visited = visited
                    )
                }
                val result = validateTicTacToe(visited)
                if (result != -1) {
                    if (result == 1) {
                        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
                            val matchesWon1 = currScore.value.matchWon1
                            _gameState.update {
                                it.copy(
                                    winnerFound = result,
                                    matchesWon1 = matchesWon1 + 1
                                )
                            }
                            currScoreDao.updatePlayer1Score(matchesWon1 + 1)
                        }
                    } else if (result == 2) {
                        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
                            val matchesWon2 = currScore.value.matchWon2
                            _gameState.update {
                                it.copy(
                                    winnerFound = result,
                                    matchesWon2 = matchesWon2 + 1
                                )
                            }
                            currScoreDao.updatePlayer2Score(matchesWon2 + 1)
                        }
                    } else {
                        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
                            val draw = currScore.value.draw
                            _gameState.update {
                                it.copy(
                                    winnerFound = result,
                                    draw = draw + 1
                                )
                            }
                            currScoreDao.updateDraw(draw + 1)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun validateTicTacToe(visited: List<MutableList<Int>>): Int {
        var allFilled = true
        for (i in 0..2) {
            var count1 = 0
            var notVisited = false
            for (j in 0..2) {
                if (visited[i][j] == -1) {
                    allFilled = false
                    notVisited = true
                    break
                }
                count1 += visited[i][j]
            }
            if (!notVisited) {
                if (count1 == 3) return 2
                else if (count1 == 0) return 1
            }
        }
        for (j in 0..2) {
            var count1 = 0
            var notVisited = false
            for (i in 0..2) {
                if (visited[i][j] == -1) {
                    notVisited = true
                    break
                }
                count1 += visited[i][j]
            }
            if (!notVisited) {
                if (count1 == 3) return 2
                else if (count1 == 0) return 1
            }
        }
        var i = 0
        var j = 0
        var count1 = 0
        var notVisited = false
        while (j < 3) {
            if (visited[i][j] == -1) {
                notVisited = true
                break
            }
            count1 += visited[i][j]
            i++
            j++
        }
        if (!notVisited) {
            if (count1 == 3) return 2
            else if (count1 == 0) return 1
        }
        i = 0
        j = 2
        count1 = 0
        notVisited = false
        while (j >= 0) {
            if (visited[i][j] == -1) {
                notVisited = true
                break
            }
            count1 += visited[i][j]
            i++
            j--
        }
        if (!notVisited) {
            if (count1 == 3) return 2
            else if (count1 == 0) return 1
        }
        if (allFilled) return 0
        return -1
    }

    fun reset(
        temp: Int,
        name1: String = "",
        name2: String = ""
    ) {
        if (temp == 1) {
            _gameState.update {
                it.copy(
                    turn = 0,
                    visited = listOf(
                        mutableListOf(-1, -1, -1),
                        mutableListOf(-1, -1, -1),
                        mutableListOf(-1, -1, -1)
                    ),
                    winnerFound = -1
                )
            }
        } else {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                currScoreDao.updatePlayer1Name(name1)
                currScoreDao.updatePlayer2Name(name2)
                currScoreDao.updatePlayer1Score(0)
                currScoreDao.updatePlayer2Score(0)
                currScoreDao.updateDraw(0)
                _gameState.update {
                    it.copy(
                        name1 = currScore.value.name1,
                        name2 = currScore.value.name2,
                        matchesWon1 = 0,
                        matchesWon2 = 0,
                        draw = 0
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun insertRecord(name1: String, name2: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            currScoreDao.insertCurrentScore(
                CurrScore(
                    id = 0,
                    name1 = name1,
                    name2 = name2,
                    matchWon1 = 0,
                    matchWon2 = 0,
                    draw = 0
                )
            )
            Log.d("latest",currScoreDao.currScore().stateIn(
                scope = viewModelScope,
                started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
                initialValue = CurrScore()
            ).value.toString())
            _gameState.update {
                it.copy(
                    name1 = currScore.value.name1,
                    name2 = currScore.value.name2,
                    turn = 0,
                    matchesWon1 = 0,
                    matchesWon2 = 0,
                    draw = 0,
                    prevRecord=true,
                    visited = listOf(
                        mutableListOf(-1, -1, -1),
                        mutableListOf(-1, -1, -1),
                        mutableListOf(-1, -1, -1)
                    ),
                )
            }
        }
    }

    private fun prevRecordExists() {
        viewModelScope.launch{
            val count = currScoreDao.prevRecordCount()
            _gameState.update {
                it.copy(
                    prevRecord = count > 0
                )
            }
            if (gameState.value.prevRecord) {
                Log.d("latest",currScore.value.toString())
                _gameState.update {
                    it.copy(
                        name1 = currScore.value.name1,
                        name2 = currScore.value.name2,
                        matchesWon1 = currScore.value.matchWon1,
                        matchesWon2 = currScore.value.matchWon2,
                        draw = currScore.value.draw,
                        prevRecord = count > 0
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
class TicTacToeViewModelFactory(private val currScoreDao: CurrScoreDao) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(TicTacToeViewModel::class.java)) {
            return TicTacToeViewModel(currScoreDao) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

CurrScore.kt:-

```
@Entity
     data class CurrScore(
     @PrimaryKey
     val id:Int=0,
     @ColumnInfo(name="Name1")
     val name1:String="",
     @ColumnInfo(name="Name2")
     val name2:String="",
     @ColumnInfo(name="MatchWon1")
     val matchWon1:Int=0,
     @ColumnInfo(name="MatchWon2")
     val matchWon2: Int=0,
     @ColumnInfo(name="Draw")
     val draw:Int=0
     )
```

CurrScoreDao.kt:-

```
@Dao
interface CurrScoreDao {
    @Insert
    suspend fun insertCurrentScore(currScore: CurrScore)

    @Query("Update CurrScore set name1=:name")
    suspend fun updatePlayer1Name(name:String)

    @Query("Update CurrScore set name2=:name")
    suspend fun updatePlayer2Name(name:String)

    @Query("Update CurrScore set matchWon1=:score")
    suspend fun updatePlayer1Score(score:Int)

    @Query("Update CurrScore set matchWon2=:score")
    suspend fun updatePlayer2Score(score:Int)

    @Query("Update CurrScore set draw=:draw")
    suspend fun updateDraw(draw:Int)

    @Query("Select count(*) from CurrScore")
    suspend fun prevRecordCount():Int

    @Query("Select * from CurrScore limit 1")
    fun currScore(): Flow<CurrScore>

}
```

I tried through logging but found out that it is not updating. If I am not wrong, Room library provides an updated flow whenever we want to access it.